# looping a training model over model classes and changing dataframe name by model class

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, pipeline

I am trying to automate a training pipeline and having some troubles to rename the input dataframes over changing model classes.

```
sample_train = [9]
sample_test = [18]
model_class = [0]


for i in sample_train:
    for j in model_class:
        # Define the training datasets -Filter the datasets with model selections
        trainX_M[j] = mldata_pd[(mldata_pd.sample_id == i) & (mldata_pd.training_set_band == j)].drop(
            ['conv_gv_band', 'sample_id', 'training_set_band'], axis=1)
        trainy_M[j] = mldata_pd[(mldata_pd.sample_id == i) & (
            mldata_pd.training_set_band == j)].iloc[:, mldata_pd.columns == 'conv_gv_band']

    trainX_M0, testX, trainy_M0, testy = train_test_split(trainX_M0, trainy_M0,
                                                          test_size=0.2,
                                                          random_state=42)
```

I expect to have `trainX_M0` when `model_class=0` but receive the error:

> NameError: name 'trainX_M' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

your variable is trainX_M and not trainX_M0 , cahgne to

```
trainX_M0[j] = mldata_pd[(mldata_pd.sample_id == i) & (mldata_pd.training_set_band == j)].drop(['conv_gv_band','sample_id','training_set_band'], axis=1)
```

or crete a list trainX_M and df append to it all of the matrixes per class

Answer (score 0):

You try to set the value at position j in `trainX_M[j] =`, same with `trainY_M[j] =`, and from the error you can read that the array `trainX_M` is not defined before. In your posted code snipped I also can not see a definition. Are you sure there is one and it is spelled the same way?

If there is none, you could initialize the array trainX_M like that (I guess equal size as model_class):

```
trainX_M = [None] * len(model_class)
```